# Бесконечный цикл в clang, в gcc - работает

Tags: c++, map

Решили добавить тесты для компилятора clang помимо gcc. В итоге в одной функции получаем бесконечный цикл, и в минимальном примере размер карты не выводится. Почему так?

```
std::unordered_multimap<int, int> map = {{1, 2},
                                         {1, 5},
                                         {2, 3},
                                         {3, 7},
                                         {5, 1}}; // какая-то инициализация

for (auto&& key_value_pair : map) {
    auto[old_key, old_value] = key_value_pair;
    auto new_value = old_value + 1; // какое-то вычисление для нового значения

    map.insert({old_key, new_value});
}

std::cout << map.size();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменять контейнер во время прохода по нему с помощью ranged for loop - плохая идея.

Конкретно в случае `unordered_multimap` есть две проблемы.

Во-первых, `.insert()` может поставить элемент как перед текущим (т.е. перед `key_value_pair` ), так и после, в зависимости от реализации.

Если `unordered_multimap` решит каждый раз будет ставить элемент после текущего, то цикл никогда не закончится.

Во вторых, что более важно:

> [`std::unordered_multimap::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/insert)
>
> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected.

Rehashing рано или поздно произойдет при добавлении очередного элемента.

Тогда вы получите неопределенное поведение, потому что итератор, который используется ranged for для прохода по `unordered_multimap`, перестанет быть валидным.